# WordPress: Setting up a page that uses post images to link to post category

Tags: wordpress

I came across this site: http://www.jfletcherdesign.com.

I want to replicate how the home page shows the featured image of all of his posts and that when you click on the image you drill down into in the specific post. I also want to replicate how you are able to click forward and next with an image to the corresponding post within a category.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for setting up this functionality?

Bonus points if you can point me to the jQuery plugin that is being used for the rollover effect on his category page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That site is based on the [Imbalance](http://wpshower.com/themes/imbalance/) theme by WPShower. It's a free theme so you can download it and check out all the source code. That should answer your first question.

To get images that act as pagination to the previous and next posts all you need to do is use the [get_adjacent_post function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post). You can use something like the code below to set it up to link an image. Stick it in the bottom of your single.php or wherever you want the pagination to appear.

```
<?php
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true);
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post(true, '', false);
?>
<?php if ($prev_post) : $prev_post_url = get_permalink($prev_post->ID); ?>
    <a class="previous-post" href="<?php echo $prev_post_url; ?>"><img src="www.site.com/previous-image.png" alt"previous post" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($next_post) : $next_post_url = get_permalink($next_post->ID); ?>
    <a class="next-post" href="<?php echo $next_post_url; ?>"><img src="www.site.com/next-image.png" alt"next post" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now for the jQuery rollover, it is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.article').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('.article-over').show();
    });
    $('.article').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('.article-over').hide();
    });
    $('.article').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.preview a img').stop().fadeTo(1000, 0.3);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.preview a img').stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }
    );
});
```

Which acts on the following HTML markup generated by the theme:

```
<li class="article li_col1" id="post-1234">

    <div class="preview">
        <a href="http://www.site.com/2013/01/post/"><img width="305" height="380" src="http://www.site.com/image/src.jpg" class="attachment-background wp-post-image" alt="" title="Cool Post"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="article-over">
        <h2><a href="http://www.site.com/2013/01/post/" title="Cool Post">Cool Post</a></h2>
        <div class="the-excerpt">
            <p>Blah blah blah this is a post excerpt...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

So basically when you first go to the site, for all the items except the first, all you see is the `.preview` div that holds the category image. The `.article-over` div is absolutely positioned over the `.preview` div but has a style of `display:none` so that you can't see it.

When the mouseenter event is fired, the `.article-over` div is displayed via `show()`, and the image inside `.preview` fades out to an opacity of 0.3 allowing you to see the `.preview` div's black background behind it. When the mouse leaves, `.article-over` is hidden, and the `.preview` image fades back to fully opaque.

If you're still stuck let me know and I'll try to explain further.